# How to add an UpperCase function to each textbox in a dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, html-table

I am trying to create a dynamic table with textboxes but I want the textboxes to be converted to upper case every time I write.

Any ideas on how to do this??

Currently this is how I am doing the dynamic table:

```
var n = 1;
function addRow(tableID,nroColumna) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    for(i=0;i<nroColumna;i++){

        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "text";
        element.name = n+"0"+i;
        element.size = "12";
        element.id = n+"0"+i;

        //element.onkeyup = function(){alert()};
        cell.appendChild(element);
    }
    n++;
}
```

I was trying to do a `document.getElementById(element.id).value.toUpperCase()` but I am getting an error with a null value for the element.id

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code with the onkeyup function activated:

```
var n = 1;
function addRow(tableID,nroColumna) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    for(i=0;i<nroColumna;i++){

        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "text";
        element.name = n+"0"+i;
        element.size = "12";
        element.id = n+"0"+i;

        element.onkeyup = function(){alert(element.id);};
        cell.appendChild(element);
    }
    n++;
}
```

And that worked. However, it uses the last element.id computed for every call to the function... so, when I created one row of 3 cells, every time I typed into a cell, it would alert "102" regardless of which cell I typed in.

This is because the onkeyup function is *dynamic*. It is called on the keyup action - not set when the object is created. So it uses the element.id value that *exists at the time of the action,* not what it was when you passed it in the first time. I hope that makes sense.

I had this issue myself on a recent project. One solution is to create a separate function for the inner workings of the for loop as such:

```
var n = 1;

function createRow (n, i) {
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.type = "text";
    element.name = n+"0"+i;
    element.size = "12";
    element.id = n+"0"+i;

    element.onkeyup = function(){alert(element.id);};

    return element;
}
function addRow(tableID,nroColumna) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    for(i=0;i<nroColumna;i++){
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        element = createRow(n, i);
        cell.appendChild(element);
    }
    n++;
}
```

This code alerts the correct element.id value.

EDIT: you can change the onkeyup() line to read:

```
element.onkeyup = function(){document.getElementById(element.id).value = document.getElementById(element.id).value.toUpperCase();};
```

And it should work as you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with a non JavaScript solution, you could apply this `CSS` to your inputs:

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

That would make the text uppercase from the beginning...

Comment: I tried that before but every textbox in the page was uppercase :/

Answer (score 2):

Darkajax's solution, works, you can target it to inputs within a table with a specific ID

with

```
#tableid input
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery it will be like

```
$('.yourClass').val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
```

or

```
$('#yourId').css({'text-transform' : 'uppercase'})
```